# Is it possible to use discord.ui.TextInput without a modal in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was trying to create a command which helps users to register their username for "something", The flow is supposed to go something like this, `command used -> Continue -> Input username (with TextInput) -> username registered`. But I couldn't find any resources on how to implement this without creating a Modal first online, could someone help?

```py
class AccountUsername(discord.ui.TextInput):
        
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(label="test")
```

```py
class AccountUsernameView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.add_item(AccountUsername())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an app_command like:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="register",description='Enter your Username')
async def inputname(interaction: discord.Interaction, your_name: str):
    print(your_name)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'you registered as {your_name}', ephemeral=True)
```

The User Input would look like [image: this]